# how to remove old entries in Additional Drivers pane in settings panel

Tags: nvidia, settings, additional-drivers

When I open 'software and updates and go to settings, there are several tabs, one of which is 'additional drivers'. Over time this has accumulated several entries and I would like to clean it out. How do I do that?

Comment: thank you. I would have marked your answer but it's only a comment

Comment: Converted to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Additional Drivers should only show what driver versions are available for install. Sometimes for compatibility reasons it is good to have multiple versions available. That however, does not mean that they are installed. The Additional Drivers will only allow for 1 driver to be installed on the system at a time for a specific hardware like video card.

Comment: Will it remove old driver files if I switch to another version in `Additional Drivers`?

Comment: @Ghazi I use command line, but it is supposed to remove the old one before doing the newer one.  It is supposed to be an all in one process.